# How to merge dataframe to each groupby group?

Tags: python, pandas, join, pandas-groupby, pandas-merge

Given df1 and df2:

df1:

| id | item | sub_item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 52 | AAA |
| 2 | 52 | AAA |
| 3 | 55 | BAA |
| 4 | 77 | CAA |
| 5 | 77 | CAA |
| 6 | 77 | CAA |
| 7 | 77 | CAB |
| 8 | 77 | CAC |

df2:

| id | color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | #11 |
| 2 | #12 |
| 3 | #13 |
| 4 | #14 |
| 5 | #17 |
| 6 | #18 |
| 7 | #19 |
| 8 | #20 |
| 9 | #21 |
| 10 | #25 |

produce df_result:

| id | item | sub_item | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 52 | AAA | #11 |
| 2 | 52 | AAA | #11 |
| 3 | 55 | BAA | #11 |
| 4 | 77 | CAA | #11 |
| 5 | 77 | CAA | #11 |
| 6 | 77 | CAA | #11 |
| 7 | 77 | CAB | #12 |
| 8 | 77 | CAC | #13 |

`id` is unimportant.  Each new sub-item, within an item group, gets new serial color number. Colors start re-assignment back to #11 for each new item.  df2 will always be long enough to cover unique sub-items within an item group.

My intuition says to use `groupby` on `df1`, then `merge` each group with `df2`, but I need help with the code to make this happen.

Comment: Why do you want to use groupby?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think that's what you want

```
merged_df = pd.merge(
        df1,df2, how="left", on="Id"
    )
```

Comment: Doesn't match the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df1["color"] = (df2.merge(df1["sub-item"].ne(df1.groupby("item")["sub-item"].transform("first"))
                                         .cumsum()
                                         .add(1)
                                         .rename("id"), 
                          how="right")["color"]
                )

>>> df1
   id  item sub-item color
0   1    52      AAA   #11
1   2    52      AAA   #11
2   3    55      BAA   #11
3   4    77      CAA   #11
4   5    77      CAA   #11
5   6    77      CAA   #11
6   7    77      CAB   #12
7   8    77      CAC   #13
```

Comment: Nice.  That is definitely in the neighborhood of what I was looking for.  I'll give it a go and let you know.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @user17749445 - I edited my answer for optimization. Please use the updated version instead.